# ColdFusion datasource within a <cfquery> tag not working

Tags: coldfusion

I'm new to ColdFusion. I added a new data source called "coldfusionproject" in CF Administrator.
[Screenshot of Connected Data Sources in CF Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fueSt.png)

As you can see, the status is "OK".

However, when I use the `datasource = "coldfusionproject"` attribute within a `<cfquery>`, I get the error that states `datasource "coldfusionproject" could not be found.`

My `<cfquery>` tag in my code looks like this ("username" and "password" values are actually the values for my local MySQL Server dB):

```
<cfquery datasource = "coldfusionproject" username = "root" password = "admin">
```

Any ideas? I'm not sure why it's not finding the data source I created in CF Admin.

Comment: Have you got more than one instance of Coldfusion setup?

Comment: Also... if you already have the user & pwd set in CFAdmin, why are you _also_ passing it in the code? Unrelated to your immediate situation (which I expect is you are not running the code on the same server as you have configured the DSN), but still a bit of a weakness here. Also: any reason yer setting up the DSN in CFAdmin (old school) as opposed to setting it up in Application.cfc?

Comment: Please excuse the newby-ness, I'm a PHP developer. How might I know if I have more than one instance set up? I installed CF through Adobe website and just followed that step by step. Didn't do anything out of the ordinary. Newby mistake on my part with the user/pwd in the code, since I already have it set in CFAdmin :) I'll remove that. The only reason I set up the DSN in CFAdmin is because it was the first method I found to do so. Didn't read about Application.cfc until later. This is a take-home project for an interview, and I was required to learn and build a simple CF app in 4 days.

Comment: No worries my questions weren't loaded... just info for solving the problem. Not sure we're any the wiser as to what's going on though (going on yer answer). Weird.

Comment: Humour us. What is the hostname:port you're using for CFAdmin, and what is the one yer using for your own work?

Comment: For CFAdmin, its `127.0.0.1:8500`. For my own work, it's `127.0.0.1:62536`. FWIW, I'm also using the "CommandBox" tool.

Comment: There's yer answer then. Yer configuring yer DSN on one CF instance (127.0.0.1:8500) and trying to use it on a different one (127.0.0.1:62536)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I solved my own problem. I created an `application.cfc` file (thanks @Adam Cameron in the comments), and added this code:

```
<cfscript>

component {

this.name = "coldfusionproject";

this.datasources = {
        coldfusionproject = {

            database    = "cold_fusion",
            host        = "127.0.0.1",
            port        = "3006",
            driver      = "MySQL5",
            username    = "root",
            password    = "pw"
        }
    };

    this.datasource = "coldfusionproject";  
}

</cfscript>
```

My app was then able to connect to my local database without errors.

Comment: It's good that you solved your problem, but I think it's a mystery as to why your initial efforts failed.

Comment: This is a better way of approaching things I reckon anyhow ("config as code" FTW). Still odd that the code can't see the DSN set up in admin though. BTW in case you end up deploying on a file system that cares about such things... it should be `Application.cfc`, not `application.cfc`. Good luck with the job.

Answer (score 0):

`<CFQUERY NAME="get" DATASOURCE="#coldfusionproject#">`
U can try this way with Hash. If you are connected to a CF administrator from IAS. Then this will work fine.No need for a password parameter.